# Free good quality small scale (1:70,000) global coastline datasets?

Tags: large-datasets

I've been searching for a few days for the most accurate world coastline datasets.. Does anyone know where l can get coastlines at scales of 1:250 000, 1:2 000 000 and 1: 70 000. I've tried using the NOAA NGDC extractor but my 1:70 000 medium resolution coastlines only cover the US and the rest of the world is omitted.

I already have 1: 1 000 000(VMap0). Please point me in the right direction of where l can easily download good quality large-scale global coastline datasets.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: 'Large Scale' is sub 1:15,000 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map#Scale_and_accuracy

Comment: @Mapperz Please, let's not criticize the OP for a perfectly valid and well-defined characterization of his/her needs.  Surely there is room for qualitative characterizations of scale to depend on context and purpose.  Wikipedia appears to acknowledge this by offering its scale pronouncements only hypothetically ("say,").

Comment: Perhaps specify which region you are interested in.

Comment: @johanvdw I'm interested in the whole world, not a single region.

Comment: I'd be happy be to proven wrong, but I think the answer is: there aren't any (integrated) global coastline datas less than <1:500,000 nominal scale, or even <1:750k, even for a price. Of course I'm curious as to what use a *global* 70k dataset would  be.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/ has coastlines 1:10m, 1:50m, and 1:110 million which should get you started. To get larger scale you are probably going to have to start searching national/regional data stores.

Comment: Thanx lant, I've already downloaded from natural-earth but  noticed that the coastlines are not as accurate as l want. My intention is to have them at different scales and since l already have the 10mil, l now need 2mil, 250thousand and 70thousand datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Tried Open Street Map?

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Coastline_error_checker

Data:
http://hypercube.telascience.org/~kleptog/

[image]

[Map data © OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA.](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

Comment: I'm using OSM datasets for my project but l want to get external data for the coastlines. The OSM data l downloaded had coastlines but my roads go over the coast

Comment: May be you could edit the coastlines to fix that problem - improving the data for every one.

Comment: @iant,that could work but I'm running out of time so l need a fast solution. But will certainly have a look at them another time so that its easier for other people who might need coastlines

Answer (score 1):

With creative cartographic techniques or more advanced geometric operations, the [Global Administrative dataset (GADM)](http://www.gadm.org/) might be of use. Of course, level 0 (countries) would be easiest.